# C++ / llvm / clang: general advice needed on approach for refactoring tool

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

I would like to create a tool that inspects if the order of method implementations in a C++ source file matches the order of method declarations in the corresponding header file.

This is a shortened version of the code I have so far:

```cpp
// #includes and namespace statements snipped
// error handling and log output also snipped

static llvm::cl::OptionCategory ClangOrderCategory("clang-order options");
static cl::extrahelp CommonHelp(CommonOptionsParser::HelpMessage);
static cl::extrahelp MoreHelp("\nMore help text...");

DeclarationMatcher MethodMatcher = cxxMethodDecl(unless(isImplicit())).bind("methodDeclaration");

class MethodPrinter : public MatchFinder::MatchCallback
{
  public:
    virtual void run(const MatchFinder::MatchResult& result)
    {
        const CXXMethodDecl* decl = result.Nodes.getNodeAs<clang::CXXMethodDecl>("methodDeclaration");

        // get parent declaration, i.e. the method's class
        const CXXRecordDecl* parentDecl = decl->getParent();
        std::string parentName = parentDecl->getNameAsString();

        SourceLocation location = decl->getLocation();
        SourceManager& manager  = result.Context->getSourceManager();

        std::string filename = manager.getFilename(location).str();

        // remove path and leave filename only
        filename = filename.substr(filename.find_last_of("/") + 1, filename.length());

        int lineNumber = manager.getSpellingLineNumber(location);
        DeclarationNameInfo nameInfo = decl->getNameInfo();
        std::string methodName = nameInfo.getName().getAsString();

        // TODO: this relies on class name == filename.[cpp|h], incl. case
        if (filename == parentName + ".h")
        {
            // TODO: store method name and line number in some kind of list
        }
        else
        if (filename == parentName + ".cpp")
        {
            // TODO: store method name and line number in a second list
        }

        // TODO: compare lists to verify method order is identical
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    CommonOptionsParser OptionsParser(argc, argv, ClangOrderCategory);
    ClangTool           Tool(OptionsParser.getCompilations(),
                             OptionsParser.getSourcePathList());

    MethodPrinter Printer;
    MatchFinder   Finder;
    Finder.addMatcher(MethodMatcher, &Printer);

    return Tool.run(newFrontendActionFactory(&Finder).get());
}
```

This obviously has quite a few shortcomings, but works for a really simple test set of one source file that includes its header file. However, as soon as a source file includes more files, `run(...)` is called for every method encountered in every `#include`.

I can't seem to find a way to access `Tool` from within `run(...)` so I can't use [`ClangTool::getSourcePaths()`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1tooling_1_1ClangTool.html#acd2b739795035287e3bfd7c569aa2435) to determine what file I am currently processing. I also looked into [`SourceManager::isInMainFile(...)`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceManager.html#a2e39268edad5a61325622987c0dd3c7a), but that only gets me method implementations and not the declarations.

After working with `clang-format` and `clang-tidy`, I was under the impression that the `clang-*` tools usage concept in general is to process one file at a time and use the shell to e.g. `find ... | xargs` or so.

Now I am beginning to think my general approach is wrong. How is this usually done ?

Could someone with more knowledge about clang than me share their thinking about how they would solve this ?